# Download Specific file from Website with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Following the documentation of BeautifulSoup, I am trying to download a specific file from a webpage. First trying to find the link that contains the file name:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://www.bancentral.gov.do/a/d/2538-mercado-cambiario")
parsed = BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")
link = parsed.find("a", text=re.compile("TASA_DOLAR_REFERENCIA_MC.xls"))
path = link.get('href')
print(f"{path}")
```

But with no success. Then trying to print every link on that page, I get no links:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get("https://www.bancentral.gov.do/a/d/2538-mercado-cambiario")
parsed = BeautifulSoup(url.text, "html.parser")
link = parsed.find_all('a')
for links in parsed.find_all("a href"):
    print(links.get('a href'))
```

It looks like the url of the file is dynamic, it adds a ?v=123456789 parameter to the end of the url, like the file version, that's why I need to download the file using the file name.

*(Eg https://cdn.bancentral.gov.do/documents/estadisticas/mercado-cambiario/documents/TASA_DOLAR_REFERENCIA_MC.xls?v=1612902983415)*

Thanks.

Comment: `link = parsed.find_all('a')` is never used. But it doesn't matter because the data you want isn't in the HTML. The page you loaded fires a request that hits https://www.bancentral.gov.do/Home/GetContentForRender with payload id=2538&languageName=es to get the HTML content containing the xlses, but these don't have the v= key, so I assume this is being added by JS. All of these links have the exact same key and it doesn't appear that it matters--I can access the file directly with a GET to the URL without the v=. Long story short, you can just download the file directly from the URL, no?

Comment: You are right @ggorlen.! I

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are dealing with a `dynamic` `JavaScript` page which is fully loaded via an `XHR` request to the following [url](https://www.bancentral.gov.do/Home/GetContentForRender) once the page loads.

Below is a direct call to the back-end API which identify the request using page id which is `2538` and then we can load your desired url.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0'
    }
    with requests.Session() as req:
        req.headers.update(headers)
        data = {
            "id": "2538",
            "languageName": "es"
        }
        r = req.post(url, data=data)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.json()['result']['article']['content'], 'lxml')
        target = soup.select_one('a[href*=TASA_DOLAR_REFERENCIA_MC]')['href']
        r = req.get(target)
        with open('data.xls', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(r.content)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('https://www.bancentral.gov.do/Home/GetContentForRender')
```